# Advantage of Proximal Gradient Descent Over Alternating Minimization Approach?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

I have a convex function $f(x)$ which I decompose it into sum of two convex functions as follow:
$g(x) + k(x)$. Where $g(x)$  is smooth and differentiable and $k(x)$ is non-smooth and non-differentiable. I can compute the proximal operator of $k(x)$ and use proximal gradient decent algorithm to solve it. but I have seen that, other people tried to solve it Alternating Minimization Approach approach.
I was wondering what are the obvious advantage of Alternating Minimization approach over prximal gradient decent.

Comment: Which "alternating miniization" approach and which proximal method are you referring to precisely? If $g$ has Lipschitz gradient and you can compute the prox of $k$ analytically then an accelerated proximal gradient methiod like FISTA is provably the best you can do (as it attains nesterovs optimal $O(L_g/\sqrt{\epsilon})$ complexity.